# How to merge multiple CSV files in a folder to a single file on Azure?

Tags: python, pandas, azure, csv, cloud

I have written this code and its showing no error. But I am not able to see that output file. Any help will be appreciated.

```
from os import chdir
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):

   result_obj = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file,encoding='utf-8') for file in list_of_files])

   result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding='utf-8')


root = "FOLDER PATH"

chdir(root)


file_pattern = ".csv"
list_of_files = [file for file in glob(root+'*.csv')]



file_out = "ConsolidateOutput.csv"
produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your setup? I ran this with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Check your folder path as well as your app path and permissions**

I ran this code with no problems. I started with 3 CSVs and ended up with one. However, there were a few configuration issues which caused me to not see the CSV at first. The full code is below with real paths for reference.

Here are the things I had to fix:

1. As it stands, this code stores in the folder where this code is located. Is that intentional? It often isn't, so go check where your `file.py` is to see if your CSV is there.
2. Check that you have the proper permissions to write to that folder. It wasn't a problem here, but it has been an issue for projects in the past.
3. Check that your root folder is correct and there are actually CSVs there. While the code throws an error when it doesn't find any CSVs on my local, maybe your setup does it differently.

Here is my full working code:

```
from os import chdir
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd


def produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out):
    result_obj = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, encoding='utf-8') for file in list_of_files])
    result_obj.to_csv(file_out, index=False, encoding='utf-8')


root = "C:\\Users\\Matthew\\PycharmProjects\\stackoverflow\\"

chdir(root)

file_pattern = ".csv"
list_of_files = [file for file in glob(root + '*.csv')]

file_out = "ConsolidateOutput.csv"
produceOneCSV(list_of_files, file_out)
```